# Building a class registry: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have this setup:

```
//./things/Base.ts
export default class Base{
  constructor(){
    console.log("HI I AM A BASE THING");
  }
}

//things.ts
import Base = require('./things/Base');

export = {
  defaultThing: Base
};

//entry.ts
import Things = require('./things');

new Things.defaultThing();
```

What I'm trying to do is build a dictionary with the keys I want for classes of a given type, letting me change the underlying implementation without touching the consuming code. This fails with the following message

```
λ tsc entry.ts
entry.ts(3,1): error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

Why is this and what's the proper idiom?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`import Base = require(...)` does not mix well with `export default class Base`.

If you add `console.dir(Base)` to `things.ts`, you will see that `Base` is actually a module there, not a class:

```
{ __esModule: true, default: [Function: Base] }
```

If you change that import in `things.ts` to

```
import Base from './things/Base';
```

then your example starts working.

The explanation is given in the [typescript language specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1133-import-require-declarations):

> An import require declaration of the form
>
> ```
>     import m = require("mod");
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the ECMAScript 2015 import declaration
>
> ```
>     import * as m from "mod";
> ```

That es6 form always imports `m` as a module, even if it contains default export.

Comment: Nice! Do you know why that happens? I was under the impression that the idiom would work the same as your proposed solution

Comment: I think I found the explanation - added it to the answer