# TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature. Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, typescript-typings

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I have this class/module:

```js
import * as Mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
import { db } from '../lib/database';

let mongoose = Mongoose;

mongoose.Promise = Promise;


export class BaseModel  {

    constructor(schemaObj: {}, modelName: string, statics?: {}) {
      let Schema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObj)

      Schema.statics.list = function () {
        return this.find()
      }

      Schema.statics.save = function (dataObj) {
        return this.save(dataObj)
      }

      if (statics) {
        for (let key in statics) {
          Schema.statics[key] = statics[key];
        }
      }
      
      return mongoose.model(modelName, Schema);
    }
    
}

let schema = {
  title:  String,
}

let Message = new BaseModel(schema, 'message');

let j = new Message({title: 'Hello World'}).save().then(function (res) {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Everything actually works buts TypeScript is complaining:

> TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

I know I missing some thing but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a class registry: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578040/building-a-class-registry-cannot-use-new-with-an-expression-whose-type-lacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the problem is in your code, the only `new` operator you are using is to create a new mongoose scheme and it looks right. Probably the problem is in mongoose typings.

The error you mentioned is typically showed when function returns another function and not the class instance (eg: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2081).

Try to update typings to the newest version or try to downgrade it to different lower version.

*(Typings are such a magic and in our projects we sometimes need to fix one specific version, because even newer path version can break the project.)*

Comment: Older and  new version did not help. in a case like this how would one add a new constructor to it ? Have looked at a lot of resources and did quite a lot of tinkering with it and just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the `* as` when you import mongoose. So it would become

`import Mongoose from 'mongoose';`