# Typescript Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a sharepoint webpart using the new sharepoint framework, which uses the microsoft graph
[as shown here:](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/call-microsoft-graph-from-your-web-part)

Here is a sample that I am using for [reference](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-aad-implicitflow).

I created a new project using the yeoman generator for sharepoint.

Installed adal: npm install adal-angular

Installed typings for adal: typings install adal --source dt --global --save

Copied the relevant parts from the WebPart.tsx file:

```
const AuthenticationContext = require('adal-angular');
import adalConfig from '../AdalConfig';
import { IAdalConfig } from '../../IAdalConfig';
import '../../WebPartAuthenticationContext';

export default class ReactClient extends React.Component<IReactClientProps, IReactClientState> {
  private authCtx: adal.AuthenticationContext;

  constructor(props: IReactClientProps, state: IReactClientState) {
    super(props);
  }

this.state = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  signedIn: false
};

const config: IAdalConfig = adalConfig;
config.popUp = true;
config.webPartId = this.props.webPartId;
config.callback = (error: any, token: string): void => {
  this.setState((previousState: IReactClientState, currentProps: IReactClientProps): IReactClientState => {
    previousState.error = error;
    previousState.signedIn = !(!this.authCtx.getCachedUser());
    return previousState;
  });
};

this.authCtx = new AuthenticationContext(config);
AuthenticationContext.prototype._singletonInstance = undefined;
```

}

The line:

```
private authCtx: adal.AuthenticationContext;
```

has no problem identifying the namespace adal that is created in the adal type file.

However, the line:

```
this.authCtx = new AuthenticationContext(config);
```

gives me the error: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature

The constructor is there in the adal type file. I don't see what's missing. I'm hoping one of you guys can shed some light on it for me.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a class registry: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578040/building-a-class-registry-cannot-use-new-with-an-expression-whose-type-lacks)

Answer (score 1):

Is `AuthenticationContext` in scope? Looks like only `adl.AuthenticationContext` is in scope.

`this.authCtx = new adl.AuthenticationContext(config);`

or

`import { AuthenticationContext } from 'path/to/adl'`

at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks, mason. That's the part I'm having trouble figuring out. I would have expected to need the namespace in `new adal.AuthenticationContext(config)` also but the example clearly has it without the namespace 'new AuthenticationContext(config)'. I left out the imports for the sake of space. I'll update the OP to include them. Sorry for the confusion.