# How to resolve ' error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am importing a .js file (so not a .ts-file) called Auth.js into my reactjs&typescript application, so in my component I have this:

```
import * as Auth from '../Auth/Auth';
..
const auth = new Auth();
```

This is part of my Auth.js:

```
    export default class Auth {
        auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
            domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
            clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
            redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
            audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
            responseType: 'token id_token',
            scope: 'openid'
        });

        constructor() {
            this.login = this.login.bind(this);
            this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
            this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
            this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this);
        }
..
```

When I run webpack I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/containers/main.tsx
(16,14): error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

How can I resolve this TS-error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a class registry: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578040/building-a-class-registry-cannot-use-new-with-an-expression-whose-type-lacks)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try by removing `* as`. You are exporting `Auth` as default. Default export property we import directly without any `*` or `{}`.

```
import Auth from '../Auth/Auth';
..
const auth = new Auth();
```

Comment: or `new Auth.Auth()` should work as well, but not sure :), if you import using `*`

Comment: This broke for me when I added the flag `'esModuleInterop': true` to my `tsconfig.json`, and the suggested fix her fixed that.