# HashId for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hashids

I'm trying to use http://hashids.org in an Angular Last version project.

I found this definition file:

```
// Type definitions for Hashids.js 1.x
// Project: https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.node.js
// Definitions by: Paulo Cesar <https://github.com/pocesar>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

/// <reference types="node" />

export default class Hashids {
    private version: string;
    private minAlphabetLength: number;
    private sepDiv: number;
    private guardDiv: number;
    private errorAlphabetLength: string;
    private errorAlphabetSpace: string;
    private alphabet: string[];
    private seps: string;
    private minHashLength: number;
    private salt: string;
    constructor(salt: string, minHashLength?: number, alphabet?: string);
    public decode(hash: string): number[];
    public encode(arg: number): string;
    public encode(arg: number[]): string;
    public encode(...args: number[]): string;
    public encodeHex(str: string): string;
    public decodeHex(hash: string): string;
    public hash(input: number, alphabet: string): string;
    public unhash(input: string[], alphabet: string): number;
}
```

but When I try to use in my Angular project using this code:

```
import * as Hashids from 'hashids';
export abstract class BaseService {
     protected getId(id: any) {
            const x = new Hashids('somesecretec');
            return x.encode(id);
     }
}
```

I got this error:

> error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a
>   call or construct signature.

In my local it works, without a problem. But I tried to compile a production setting and it doesn't work.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't enough because this mostly depends on how you use this definition. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem - stackblitz, a repo, etc.

Comment: Issue is with the import of Hashids, please share how are you importing Hashids

Comment: I updated the code with my imports. @NagaSaiA

Comment: I updated the code with my imports. @estus

Comment: @AFetter, try import removing  * as , error  may be due to default export

Comment: import Hashids from 'hashids';

Comment: It's `default` export in definitions. It's supposed to be used with default import, not `*`. Since it's CommonJS module, it likely should be used with esModuleInterop option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49722246/3731501

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve ' error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46558215/how-to-resolve-error-ts2351-cannot-use-new-with-an-expression-whose-type-la)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is with the way of Hashids import, use below option to import hashids as default

```
import Hashids from 'hashids';
```

Use * or {} for named imports and Hashids throw below error on importing as named import (other than name default)

```
error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

Using default name (as default export is also a named export with name default)

```
import {default as Hashids} from "hashids";
```